# The last 2 columns of the 9 column table not appearing in the output

Tags: formatting

I have a table which has 9 columns and the code of which is

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin {table}[h]

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

\hline

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\

Vector Indicator & $X_i$ & $Y_i$ & $d_i$ & $Z_i+d_i \cdot \arctan(2^{-1})$ & $\sum_{0}^{\infty}d_i \cdot \arctan(2^{-i})$ & i & $2^{-i}$ & $\arctan(2^{-i})$\\

X0,Y0 & 0.920505 & 0.390731 & -1 & 23.000 & -45 & 0 & 1 & 45\\
X1,Y1 & 1.311235982 & -0.52977372 & 1 & -22 & -18.43494882 & 1 & 0.5 & 26.56505\\
0 & 1 & 45\\

X2,Y2 & 1.576122844 & 0.125844266 & -1 & 4.565051177 & -32.47119229 & 2 & 0.25 & 14.03624 \\

X3,Y3 & 1.607583911 & -0.26818645 & 1 & -9.471192291 & -25.34617594 & 3 & 0.125 & 7.12502 \\ 

X4,Y4 & 1.641107217 & -0.06723846 & 1 & -2.346175942 & -21.76984157 & 4 & 0.0625 & 3.57633\\

X5,Y5 & 1.64530962 &    0.035330745 & -1 &  1.230158433 & -23.55975218 &    5 & 0.03125 &   1.78991\\

X6,Y6 & 1.646413706 &   -0.01608518 &   1 & -0.559752175 &  -22.66457846 &  6 & 0.015625 & 0.89517\\

X7,Y7 & 1.646665037 & 0.009640033 & -1 &    0.335421535 & -23.11219264 &    7 & 0.0078125 & 0.44761\\

X8,Y8 & 1.64674035 &    -0.00322454 &   1 & -0.112192636 &  -22.88838214 &  8 & 0.00390625 &    0.22381\\

X9,Y9 & 1.646752945 &   0.003208042 &   -1 &    0.111617865 &   -23.00028781 &  9 & 0.001953125 &   0.11191\\

X10,Y10 & 1.646759211 & -8.27E-06 & 1 & -0.000287813 &  -22.94433492 &  10 &    0.000976563 &   0.05595\\

X11,Y11 &   1.646759219 &   0.001599891 &   -1 &    0.055665079 &   -22.97231137 &  11 &    0.000488281 &   0.02798\\

X12,Y12 &   1.64676 &   0.00079581 &    -1 &    0.027688627 &   -22.9862996 &   12 &    0.000244141 &   0.01399\\

X13,Y13 & 1.646760195 & 0.000393768 &   -1 &    0.0137004 & -22.99329371 &  13 &    0.00012207 &    0.00699 \\

X14,Y14 &   1.646760243 &   0.000192748 &   -1 &    0.006706286 & -22.99679077 &    14 &    6.10E-05 &  0.0035\\

X15,Y15 &   1.646760255 &   9.22E-05 &  -1 &    0.003209229 &   -22.9985393 &   15 &    3.05E-05 &  0.00175\\

X16,Y16 & 1.646760257 & 4.20E-05 &  -1 & 0.001460701 &  -22.99941356 &  16 &    1.53E-05 &  0.00087 \\

\hline



\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end {table}

\end{document}
```

In the output, the table is appearing as below

[image]

How can I get the last 2 columns to appear in the output?

Comment: the table is wider than the page (much wider) `Overfull \hbox (237.54243pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--57` so you need to do something, make it smaller, eg `\small` or reformat it, or print less decimal places,  or ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How should i use this \small command?

Comment: @ShraySharan Do you really need 8 digits after a comma? Say, 4 digits and some manipulation in first lines may tranform your table to a fitting one.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke What is this manipulation that you are talking about?

Comment: are all those decimal places really significant, or are they just taking up space?

Comment: @ShraySharan For example you can split formulas into two lines. It is not beautiful, but space-saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shrank as much as possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\centering

\sisetup{group-digits=false}

\scriptsize
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-4.25pt}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=1.9]
  S[table-format=-1.9]
  S[table-format=-1.0]
  S[table-format=-2.9]
  S[table-format=-2.9]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=1.9]
  S[table-format=2.5]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9}\\
\midrule
VI & {$X_i$} & {$Y_i$} & {$d_i$} &
  {$f(Z_i,d_i)$} &
  {$S$} & {$i$} &
  {$2^{-i}$} & {$g(i)$}\\
\midrule
X0,Y0 & 0.920505 & 0.390731 & -1 & 23.000 & -45 & 0 & 1 & 45\\
X1,Y1 & 1.311235982 & -0.52977372 & 1 & -22 & -18.43494882 & 1 & 0.5 & 26.56505\\
0 & 1 & 45\\

X2,Y2   & 1.576122844 &  0.125844266 & -1 &  4.565051177 & -32.47119229 &  2 & 0.25        & 14.03624 \\

X3,Y3   & 1.607583911 & -0.26818645  &  1 & -9.471192291 & -25.34617594 &  3 & 0.125       & 7.12502 \\ 

X4,Y4   & 1.641107217 & -0.06723846  &  1 & -2.346175942 & -21.76984157 &  4 & 0.0625      & 3.57633\\

X5,Y5   & 1.64530962  &  0.035330745 & -1 &  1.230158433 & -23.55975218 &  5 & 0.03125     & 1.78991\\

X6,Y6   & 1.646413706 & -0.01608518  &  1 & -0.559752175 & -22.66457846 &  6 & 0.015625    & 0.89517\\

X7,Y7   & 1.646665037 &  0.009640033 & -1 &  0.335421535 & -23.11219264 &  7 & 0.0078125   & 0.44761\\

X8,Y8   & 1.64674035  & -0.00322454  &  1 & -0.112192636 & -22.88838214 &  8 & 0.00390625  & 0.22381\\

X9,Y9   & 1.646752945 &  0.003208042 & -1 &  0.111617865 & -23.00028781 &  9 & 0.001953125 & 0.11191\\

X10,Y10 & 1.646759211 & -0.00000827  &  1 & -0.000287813 & -22.94433492 & 10 & 0.000976563 & 0.05595\\

X11,Y11 & 1.646759219 &  0.001599891 & -1 &  0.055665079 & -22.97231137 & 11 & 0.000488281 & 0.02798\\

X12,Y12 & 1.64676     &  0.00079581  & -1 &  0.027688627 & -22.9862996  & 12 & 0.000244141 & 0.01399\\

X13,Y13 & 1.646760195 &  0.000393768 & -1 &  0.0137004   & -22.99329371 & 13 & 0.00012207  & 0.00699\\

X14,Y14 & 1.646760243 &  0.000192748 & -1 &  0.006706286 & -22.99679077 & 14 & 0.000061    & 0.0035\\

X15,Y15 & 1.646760255 &  0.0000922   & -1 &  0.003209229 & -22.9985393  & 15 & 0.0000305   & 0.00175\\

X16,Y16 & 1.646760257 &  0.000042    & -1 &  0.001460701 & -22.99941356 & 16 & .0000153    & 0.00087\\

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l@{}}{VI means Vector Indicator} \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l@{}}{$f(Z_i,d_i)=Z_i+d_i \cdot \arctan(2^{-1})$} \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l@{}}{$S=\sum_{0}^{\infty}d_i \cdot \arctan(2^{-i})$} \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l@{}}{$g(i)=\arctan(2^{-i})$}
\end{tabular}

\end {table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost to 400K! :-)

Comment: @egreg There are no vertical lines in the above table to separate the table columns. How can I do that?

Comment: @ShraySharan You can add them, if you really want; but vertical rules should be avoided in tables: they hinder reading, rather than helping it.

Comment: @egreg I just wanted to know to understand how it's done

Comment: @ShraySharan Change all the `\...rule` commands to `\hline` and add `|` between the column specifiers where you want the rule.

Comment: @egreg I don't understand what the column specifiers are here.. Normally we have a \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} but here I don't see that in this code

Comment: @ShraySharan `\begin{tabular}{ | l | S[table-format=1.9] | ...}`: `S[table-format=1.9]` is a column specifier just like `c`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26708/discussion-between-shray-sharan-and-egreg).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

There are some issues with the data in the table itself. First, you're mixing the exponential notation with long floating point notation. Second, two-word headings can be written on two lines like `Vector Indicator` and `$\sum_{0}^{\infty}d_i \cdot \arctan(2^{-i})$`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs} % sidewaystable
\begin{document}

\begin {sidewaystable}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{9}{c}}
\toprule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\ \midrule
Vector Indicator & $X_i$ & $Y_i$ & $d_i$ & $Z_i+d_i \cdot \arctan(2^{-1})$ & $\sum_{0}^{\infty}d_i \cdot \arctan(2^{-i})$ & i & $2^{-i}$ & $\arctan(2^{-i})$\\
X0,Y0 & 0.920505 & 0.390731 & -1 & 23.000 & -45 & 0 & 1 & 45\\
X1,Y1 & 1.311235982 & -0.52977372 & 1 & -22 & -18.43494882 & 1 & 0.5 & 26.56505\\
0 & 1 & 45 &&&&&&\\
X2,Y2 & 1.576122844 & 0.125844266 & -1 & 4.565051177 & -32.47119229 & 2 & 0.25 & 14.03624 \\
X3,Y3 & 1.607583911 & -0.26818645 & 1 & -9.471192291 & -25.34617594 & 3 & 0.125 & 7.12502 \\ 
X4,Y4 & 1.641107217 & -0.06723846 & 1 & -2.346175942 & -21.76984157 & 4 & 0.0625 & 3.57633\\
X5,Y5 & 1.64530962 &    0.035330745 & -1 &  1.230158433 & -23.55975218 &    5 & 0.03125 &   1.78991\\
X6,Y6 & 1.646413706 &   -0.01608518 &   1 & -0.559752175 &  -22.66457846 &  6 & 0.015625 & 0.89517\\
X7,Y7 & 1.646665037 & 0.009640033 & -1 &    0.335421535 & -23.11219264 &    7 & 0.0078125 & 0.44761\\
X8,Y8 & 1.64674035 &    -0.00322454 &   1 & -0.112192636 &  -22.88838214 &  8 & 0.00390625 &    0.22381\\
X9,Y9 & 1.646752945 &   0.003208042 &   -1 &    0.111617865 &   -23.00028781 &  9 & 0.001953125 &   0.11191\\
X10,Y10 & 1.646759211 & -8.27E-06 & 1 & -0.000287813 &  -22.94433492 &  10 &    0.000976563 &   0.05595\\
X11,Y11 &   1.646759219 &   0.001599891 &   -1 &    0.055665079 &   -22.97231137 &  11 &    0.000488281 &   0.02798\\
X12,Y12 &   1.64676 &   0.00079581 &    -1 &    0.027688627 &   -22.9862996 &   12 &    0.000244141 &   0.01399\\
X13,Y13 & 1.646760195 & 0.000393768 &   -1 &    0.0137004 & -22.99329371 &  13 &    0.00012207 &    0.00699 \\
X14,Y14 &   1.646760243 &   0.000192748 &   -1 &    0.006706286 & -22.99679077 &    14 &    6.10E-05 &  0.0035\\
X15,Y15 &   1.646760255 &   9.22E-05 &  -1 &    0.003209229 &   -22.9985393 &   15 &    3.05E-05 &  0.00175\\
X16,Y16 & 1.646760257 & 4.20E-05 &  -1 & 0.001460701 &  -22.99941356 &  16 &    1.53E-05 &  0.00087 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end {sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Using `\tiny` and `\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1.5pt}` we get the following unacceptably tiny table:

[image]

Another try:

[image]

With the following modifications:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % sidewaystable
\begin{document}

\begin {table}[htbp]
\centering\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{9}{c}@{}}
\toprule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\ 
{Vector } &          &       &       & $Z_i+d_i \times$ & $\sum_{0}^{\infty}d_i \times$ &   &          &                 \\
{ Indicator} & $X_i$ & $Y_i$ & $d_i$ & $\arctan(1/2)$  & $\arctan(1/2)$               & i & $2^{-i}$ & $\arctan(2^{-i})$\\
\midrule
X0,Y0 & 0.920505 & 0.390731 & -1 & 23.000 & -45 & 0 & 1 & 45\\
X1,Y1 & 1.311235982 & -0.52977372 & 1 & -22 & -18.43494882 & 1 & 0.5 & 26.56505\\
0 & 1 & 45 &&&&&&\\
X2,Y2 & 1.576122844 & 0.125844266 & -1 & 4.565051177 & -32.47119229 & 2 & 0.25 & 14.03624 \\
X3,Y3 & 1.607583911 & -0.26818645 & 1 & -9.471192291 & -25.34617594 & 3 & 1.25E-1 & 7.12502 \\ 
X4,Y4 & 1.641107217 & -0.06723846 & 1 & -2.346175942 & -21.76984157 & 4 & 6.25E-2 & 3.57633\\
X5,Y5 & 1.64530962 &    0.035330745 & -1 &  1.230158433 & -23.55975218 &    5 & 3.12E-2 &   1.78991\\
X6,Y6 & 1.646413706 &   -0.01608518 &   1 & -0.559752175 &  -22.66457846 &  6 & 1.56E-2 & 0.89517\\
X7,Y7 & 1.646665037 & 0.009640033 & -1 &    0.335421535 & -23.11219264 &    7 & 7.81E-3 & 0.44761\\
X8,Y8 & 1.64674035 &    -0.00322454 &   1 & -0.112192636 &  -22.88838214 &  8 & 3.91E-3 &    0.22381\\
X9,Y9 & 1.646752945 &   0.003208042 &   -1 &    0.111617865 &   -23.00028781 &  9 &1.95E-3 &   0.11191\\
X10,Y10 & 1.646759211 & -8.27E-06 & 1 & -0.000287813 &  -22.94433492 &  10 &    9.76E-4 &   0.05595\\
X11,Y11 &   1.646759219 &   0.001599891 &   -1 &    0.055665079 &   -22.97231137 &  11 &  4.88E-4 &   0.02798\\
X12,Y12 &   1.64676 &   0.00079581 &    -1 &    0.027688627 &   -22.9862996 &   12 &    2.44E-4 &   0.01399\\
X13,Y13 & 1.646760195 & 0.000393768 &   -1 &    0.0137004 & -22.99329371 &  13 &   1.22E-4 &    0.00699 \\
X14,Y14 &   1.646760243 &   0.000192748 &   -1 &    0.006706286 & -22.99679077 &    14 &    6.10E-5 &  0.0035\\
X15,Y15 &   1.646760255 &   9.22E-05 &  -1 &    0.003209229 &   -22.9985393 &   15 &    3.05E-5 &  0.00175\\
X16,Y16 & 1.646760257 & 4.20E-05 &  -1 & 0.001460701 &  -22.99941356 &  16 &    1.53E-5 &  0.00087 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't have the table sideways. I have to have it the normal way

Comment: @ShraySharan Your table is wider than what is possible by any technique in it's horizontal orientation. The only way to keep it horizontal is to use a `\tiny` text an reduce `\tabcolsep` to `2pt`, e.g., which will render the table totally unreadable.

Comment: @ShraySharan See the last picture!

Comment: That is right... It's not very readable.

Comment: What do you suggest then?

Comment: @ShraySharan See the next try. I re-formated some columns' heads and some numbers besides shrinking inter-column spacing to `4pt` and using a smaller font but more readable. I suggest two more actions you should try. The `x_i` and `y_i` columns have numbers which can be written as the `2^{i}` column. Then, you can improve the table alot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses the built-in rounding capabilities of the `siunitx` package to display just 5 significant digits in six of the nine columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry} % choose margins suitably
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,
         round-precision=5,
         group-digits=false,
         scientific-notation = fixed, 
         fixed-exponent = 0}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\medmuskip{0mu} % no space around "+" symbols
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{} c     
               S[table-format= 1.5]
               S[table-format=-1.5]
               S[table-format=-1.0]
               S[table-format=-2.5]
               S[table-format=-2.5]
               S[table-format= 2.0]
               S[table-format= 1.5]
               S[table-format= 2.5] @{}}
\toprule
1 & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9}\\

\text{Vect.\ Ind.} & {X_i} & {Y_i} & {d_i} 
& {Z_i+d_i \arctan \frac12} 
& {\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}d_i \arctan \frac{1}{2^i}} 
& {i} & {2^{-i}} & \arctan 2^{-i}\\
\midrule
X0,Y0 & 0.920505 & 0.390731 & -1 & 23.000 & -45 & 0 & 1 & 45\\
X1,Y1 & 1.311235982 & -0.52977372 & 1 & -22 & -18.43494882 & 1 & 0.5 & 26.56505\\
0 & 1 & 45\\

X2,Y2 & 1.576122844 & 0.125844266 & -1 & 4.565051177 & -32.47119229 & 2 & 0.25 & 14.03624 \\

X3,Y3 & 1.607583911 & -0.26818645 & 1 & -9.471192291 & -25.34617594 & 3 & 0.125 & 7.12502 \\ 

X4,Y4 & 1.641107217 & -0.06723846 & 1 & -2.346175942 & -21.76984157 & 4 & 0.0625 & 3.57633\\

X5,Y5 & 1.64530962 &    0.035330745 & -1 &  1.230158433 & -23.55975218 &    5 & 0.03125 &   1.78991\\

X6,Y6 & 1.646413706 &   -0.01608518 &   1 & -0.559752175 &  -22.66457846 &  6 & 0.015625 & 0.89517\\

X7,Y7 & 1.646665037 & 0.009640033 & -1 &    0.335421535 & -23.11219264 &    7 & 0.0078125 & 0.44761\\

X8,Y8 & 1.64674035 &    -0.00322454 &   1 & -0.112192636 &  -22.88838214 &  8 & 0.00390625 &    0.22381\\

X9,Y9 & 1.646752945 &   0.003208042 &   -1 &    0.111617865 &   -23.00028781 &  9 & 0.001953125 &   0.11191\\

X10,Y10 & 1.646759211 & -8.27E-06 & 1 & -0.000287813 &  -22.94433492 &  10 &    0.000976563 &   0.05595\\

X11,Y11 &   1.646759219 &   0.001599891 &   -1 &    0.055665079 &   -22.97231137 &  11 &    0.000488281 &   0.02798\\

X12,Y12 &   1.64676 &   0.00079581 &    -1 &    0.027688627 &   -22.9862996 &   12 &    0.000244141 &   0.01399\\

X13,Y13 & 1.646760195 & 0.000393768 &   -1 &    0.0137004 & -22.99329371 &  13 &    0.00012207 &    0.00699 \\

X14,Y14 &   1.646760243 &   0.000192748 &   -1 &    0.006706286 & -22.99679077 &    14 &    6.10E-05 &  0.0035\\

X15,Y15 &   1.646760255 &   9.22E-05 &  -1 &    0.003209229 &   -22.9985393 &   15 &    3.05E-05 &  0.00175\\

X16,Y16 & 1.646760257 & 4.20E-05 &  -1 & 0.001460701 &  -22.99941356 &  16 &    1.53E-05 &  0.00087 \\

\bottomrule
\end{array}$


\end {table}

\end{document}
```